# Stop cursor from jumping to end of line - SAP UI5

Tags: validation, sapui5, string-formatting

I am trying to remove leading/trailing/in-between spaces from my input box text value. So that user that enter only one word. I have given a `liveChange` event to ensure we restrict the user does not enter space.

While the below code fulfills that purpose, issue is when, user places cursor on some character in-between and backspaces it or start typing there, the cursor keeps jumping to the end of the line. How to resolve this issue. I did read some blogs and everywhere the solution is to set a `selectionRange` and capture `startSelection` and endSelection values, but I am not able to. `oEvent.getSource().setSelectionRange()` etc throws error. Any feedback/ideas?

**Controller.js**

```
trimSpaces: function(oEvent) {//on liveChange event
        var item= oEvent.getSource().getValue().replace(/\s/g, "");
        //How to capture start, end values 
        oEvent.getSource().setSelectionRange(start, end) // throws error
        oEvent.getSource().setValue(item.toUpperCase());
    },
```

Alternatively, why does the following does not work. My page simply does not load if I use constraints.

**View.xml**

```
<Input value="{path: 'modelName>/ItemNo', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String', 
constraints: {search: '^\w[a-zA-Z@#0-9.]*$'}}" liveChange="trimSpaces" 
fieldGroupIds="FG1"/>
```

Comment: Hope [Mask Input](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.MaskInput/sample/sap.m.sample.MaskInput) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can`t find the documentation for this anymore...

Anyways, liveChange should not trigger a "render" of the control. You can do there validation, use the input for search, store the value etc. you must not change the value.

Use a [formatter](https://inui.io/sap-ui5-formatter/), or even a [custom type](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/09/16/custom-data-types-in-sapui5/)